# PHP variable additions

Tags: php

Hey does anyone know a reason why this is not working? its not calculating any of the additions and just entering 0 into the database. Any help would be great, thank you!.

```
$member_id = //users member id in database//
$track = //the track results being updated//
$engine = //the engine id from the members table in database//

$engine_points_system = array();
$engine_points_system["qualpos1"] = 30; 
$engine_points_system["qualpos2"] = 20;
$engine_points_system["qualpos3"] = 18;
$engine_points_system["qualpos4"] = 17;
$engine_points_system["qualpos5"] = 16;

$enginepoints = 0;
$qualifyingpoints = 0;

$results_query = mysql_query("SELECT pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4, pos_5 
from engine_qualifying_results WHERE track_id = '$track'")
or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($results_query);

$enginequalifying = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
     $enginequalifying["pos$i"] = $row['pos_$i'];
}

for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) {
    if($engine == $enginequalifying["pos$i"]){              
        $enginepoints += $engine_points_system["qualpos$i"];
        $qualifyingpoints += $engine_points_system["qualpos$i"];
    }
}

$results_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member_results (member_id, engine_points)              
VALUES ('$member_id', $enginepoints')")
or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Because of the simple quotes `'pos_$i'` so $i is literally '$i'?

Comment: And what do `$engine` and `$enginequlifying` actually contain?

Comment: What's the point of `$enginequalifying`?  Couldn't you just use `$row` in its place?

Comment: can you do `var_dump($row);` to make sure you are getting any results?

Comment: and there is a stray ' in the insert ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$enginequalifying["pos$i"] = $row['pos_$i'];
```

In this line you have `'pos_$i'`.  This is the literal string `'pos_$i'`.  You should use `"pos_$i"` instead.

```
$enginequalifying["pos$i"] = $row["pos_$i"];
```

**UPDATE**:

In your code `$enginequalifying` is redundant, and not needed.  You can just use `$row` in its place.

```
for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++){
  if($engine == $row["pos_$i"]){              
    $enginepoints += $engine_points_system["qualpos$i"];
    $qualifyingpoints += $engine_points_system["qualpos$i"];
  }
}
```

Also, as @ax. points out, you have an extra `'` (or a missing `'`) in your INSERT.

```
$results_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member_results (member_id, engine_points)
  VALUES ('$member_id', '$enginepoints')")
or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! such a small thing, works fine now!. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code:

```
<?php
$i = 5;

print "i is $i";
print "\n";
print 'i is $i';

?>
```

You'd expect it to print:

```
i is 5
i is 5
```

But instead, it will print:

```
i is 5
i is $i
```

This happens because when the string is wrapped in single quotes, `$i` is not evaluated. It is just the string `$i`.

To fix the code, try replacing this line:

```
$enginequalifying["pos$i"] = $row['pos_$i'];
```

With this line:

```
$enginequalifying["pos$i"] = $row["pos_$i"];
```

Quotes make a difference.

---

And by the way, **ESCAPE YOUR SQL!!!**. Please?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too ugly to put into a comment: You could bypass the entire loop to build the enginequalifying array by simply doing:

```
SELECT pos_1 AS pos1, pos_2 AS pos2, etc...
```

for your query, then simply having:

```
$enginequalifying = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

It's a waste of CPU cycles to have PHP fetch/rename database fields for you when a simple `as` alias in the original query string can accomplish the exact same thing.

And incidentally, this will also remove the string-quoting error you've got that Rocket pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will make these changes!.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to say without knowing what you have in your database.

But I can tell you that you have a syntax error in the last SQL query ($enginepoints ends with a quote).